# cron job that does git fetch: is it thread safe?

Tags: git, cron

To save myself the annoyance of having to git fetch (I work on multiple repos every day) I am creating a cron job that runs git fetch in each of my repos. I would like to do it every 15 minutes. So it's possible that git fetch will be run at the same time as I am doing other git operations (add, commit, rebase, etc.) Can that cause issues?

```
#!/bin/bash

for repo in <repos>; do
    pushd $HOME/$repo
    git fetch
    popd
done

date >> /var/cache/git-fetch-all-repos/fetch-times
```

Comment: There is no threading in either Git or your shell. Are you trying to ask if  this is concurrency-safe?

Comment: Note that you might want to switch to the newfangled `git maintenance` stuff once it's supported on your system. This doesn't do anything your script doesn't already do though.

Comment: @tripleee, yes, I meant "concurrency-safe", but I was not aware of that term.

Comment: @torek The prefetch feature of `git maintenance` solves my problem. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a default configuration of the remote refs being stored in `refs/remotes/$remotename/$ref`, no, there won't be a problem. `git fetch` will only affect refs stored in the `refs/remotes` namespace, while all local operations update the `refs/heads` namespace.

Two caveats though:

1. Tags always go to `refs/tags`, so creating tags with the same name at the same time as fetching could pose problems. Git will let you know with a warning.
2. `git push` will also update the `refs/remote` namespace. Pushing the same branch that has changed on the remote while fetching it might also give you non-deterministic behavior.

PS. Your script doesn't need Bash nor `pushd`/`popd`, Git can be instructed to use a different directory from the current working directory: `for repo in $repos; do git -C "$HOME/$repo" fetch; done`